# Get the output from the ajax call

Tags: php, ajax, jquery

I am trying to get the value of the output from ajax call. What i get is NULL, what ever I do.
My guess is that my code has wrong structure, and I hope that someone who know ajax well, will spot my mistake:

I have the following code in my php. This code works, I have tested, and it prints the expected output:

```
  $output_string = array();
            foreach ($resultfromdb as $key) {

               if (($key) && ($key[0]['username'] !="")) {
                   //echo "Username is already taken";
                   $output_string = array('outputmsg' => 'User name is already taken');       
               } else {

                   //$success = "User name is already in use";
                     $output_string = array('outputmsg' => 'User name is free for use');
               }                 
            }

           echo json_encode($output_string);
```

Here is my js. file

```
// list all variables used here...
var
regform = $('#reg-form'),
memberusername = $('#memberusername'),
memberpassword = $('#memberpassword'),
memberemail = $('#memberemail'),
memberconfirmpassword = $('#memberconfirmpassword');

regform.submit(function(e) {  
       e.preventDefault();
        var memberusername = $(this).find("#memberusername").val();
        var memberemail = $(this).find("#memberemail").val();
        var memberpassword = $(this).find("#memberpassword").val();
        var memberconfirmpassword = $(this).find("#memberconfirmpassword").val();

       var url = $(this).attr("action");

       console.log(url);
        return $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url: $(this).attr("action"),
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {memberusername: memberusername, memberemail: memberemail, memberpassword: memberpassword},

        success: function(result){
               // $('#result_table').append(output_string);
               alert(result);
               alert(output_string);
               alert(result.output_string);
               console.log(result.output_string);
            } // End of success function of ajax form
        }); // End of ajax call 

});
```

Both, alert and console.log prints null... Instead of value of the variable $output_string. Any help?

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you try `json_encode($output_string, true);`

Comment: I just did, it doesn't work. Returns null...

Comment: Fire up Fiddler2 and make sure your PHP works.

Answer (score -1):

If your PHP code is working well and creating array then you have to parse the JSON output in success function.

```
success : function(result){
    var responseData = $.parseJSON(result);
    alert(responseData.output_string);
}
```

Comment: Setting dataType json tells the ajax function to do this automatically

Comment: Hi Rajasekhar I get the following error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'output_string' of null